# Google Cloud - access SQL Server database on cloud server from local computer via Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, connection, cloud

I'm trying to connect to a database hosted on a Windows 2008 Google Cloud server. I have tried the following:

- Disable the firewall entirely.
- Added firewall rules under: "Google Cloud Platform" - Networking - Firewall rules.
- I enabled TCP connections to the SQL Server Instance.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: How can I connect to my database hosted on a google cloud server from my desktop?